# Clear credentials from UIWebView with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, uiwebview

Some context:

This is a `rails` 4.2 web app using `devise` and `omniauth-facebook` which sets `true` for `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`

From a URL in Safari, users can add the web app to their iOS device's home screen.

The issue here is that when users login w/ Facebook for the second time, it authenticates with the same user as before, even if the user logged out from the web app and from Facebook in Safari.

> In other words, once you login with Facebook, the web app(UIWebView), applies the same credentials every time. Regardless of your Facebook's current user in Safari or if you logged out from the web app.

That happens even if the web app - UIWebView got removed from the iOS device's home screen.

This functionality works fine from browsers - Safari, Mobile Safari, and Chrome.

I found that Safari and UIWebView save data in different places, but not sure **how to access UIWebView data** (cookies/session/credentials) to remove it.

I would like to do that via JavaScript. However, I'm open to other options. Just please take in consideration that this is a Rails app.

The code:

**Gemfile**

```
gem "rails",              "~> 4.2"
gem "devise",             "~> 3.5"
gem "omniauth-facebook",  "~> 3.0"
```

**application.html.haml**

```
%head
  %meta{ name: "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", content: "yes" }/
```

**view** (HAML)

```
= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do
  .css_classes Sign Out
```

**sessions_controller.rb** - from Devise

```
def destroy
  super
  cookies.clear
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` cookies are generally stored in `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies`.  There are some other goodies stored in that singleton as well.  I have a few ideas:

1. Verify that in fact your ruby call is clearing the cookies by logging out and then logging all of the cookies in `sharedHTTPCookieStorage`.  If the cookies aren't cleared, clear them manually.
2. The device's Safari settings may be interfering with the storage and removal of cookies.  Verify your cookie accept policy: `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always`
3. Consider using a `WKWebView` and the not-so-documented `WKProcessPool` to flush and manage cookies.

I realize these are not pure JavaScript options.  I'm not sure if what you're asking is possible via the JavaScript bridge.

Comment: Thanks JAL. How can I access `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies`? Googling that, I found: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html But I don't have any experience with Swift/Objective-C. So that, I don't know even were to look.

Comment: @Horacio Are you using Objective-C or Swift?  Because you mentioned `UIWebView`, I assumed you have a shell web view app that loads a URL.  Depending on your language, I can provide a code snippet to access the cookies from the cookie storage.

Comment: Unless you are just using Safari and are creating a website shortcut for your webpage and don't have a shell app.

Comment: This is a 'pure' Rails/JavaScript project . And I got the `UIWebView` by adding to the head `%meta{ name: "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", content: "yes" }/`. So that, a user can add the 'url' to home screen, and then have a 'kind-of' native experience.

Comment: @Horacio I see, then my answer probably will not suit you.  How do you traditionally retrieve cookies via JavaScript?  Does `document.cookie` work?

Comment: Not sure how to get them via JavaScript, but I get cookies via Rails Controller. `document.cookie` returns an empty string.